# Using template type to generate unique member names for that template type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

This use case comes from wanting to implement a compile-time event bus data structure that only listens/registers/unregisters specifically for the provided template arguments.

Starting with a naive implemention lets say we have the following classes `AListener`, `AEvent`, `BListener`, `BEvent`.

I want my `EventBus` class to look like this:

```
class EventBus {
    std::vector<AListener*> aListeners;
    std::vector<BListener*> bListeners;

public:
    void registerListener(AListener& listener);
    void unregisterListener(AListener& listener);
    void sendEvent(AEvent event);

    void registerListener(BListener& listener);
    void unregisterListener(BListener& listener);
    void sendEvent(BEvent event);
};
```

Is there a way I can template it and recursively construct the class? For example:

```
EventBus<AListener, AEvent, BListener, BEvent> eventBus;

AListener aListener;
eventBus.registerListener(aListener);

AEvent aEvent;
eventBus.sendEvent(aEvent);

BListener bListener;
eventBus.registerListener(bListener);

BEvent bEvent;
eventBus.sendEvent(bEvent);
```

Preferably it'd be nice to make a new `vector` for each listener type because it would be inefficient to put all the pointers in one list since a long list of irrelevant listeners would be a waste of performance. Since the event bus is going to have a lot of events going through it, performance is important. Iterating over only the ones we care about is desired.

Finally, assume that we will not specialize any listener so we don't have to worry about inheritance here, all classes in the template list are considered to be final.

**My problem:**

How do I get around naming? While I assume specializing templates in the recursive definition via method overloading is okay because the compiler will hopefully do the ideal thing... I'm not sure how to handle the different member names.

My plan was to take the list and pull off two members, sort of like this (*NOTE this is pseudo-code and almost certainly does not compile, or if it does it is by pure chance*):

```
// Pseudocodey C++ template rough idea
template <typename Listener, typename Event, typename Args...>
class EventBus : public EventBus<Args...> {
    // ???

public:
    void registerListener(Listener& listener) {
        // emplace back
    }

    void unregisterListener(Listener& listener) {
        // erase remove
    }

    void sendEvent(Event event) {
        // send for each
    }
};
```

Of course unless there is a better way? Is this possible?

Comment: I know it could be something private, but what do you expect to gain from this kind of implementation?

Comment: @miradham I don't understand what you mean by gain, so if I have to guess at what you mean (and what I write may not be correct because of the ambiguity due to your word choice): Very performant code, while also allowing me to write the minimal amount of code possible to add new listeners and types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a class to handle Listener/event:

```
template <typename Listener, Event>
class EventHandler {
    std::vector<Listener*> mListeners;
public:
    void registerListener(Listener& listener);
    void unregisterListener(Listener& listener);
    void sendEvent(Event event);
};
```

Then, your class which handles all would be:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class EventBus : Ts...
{
public:
    using Ts::registerListener...;    // Requires C++17
    using Ts::unregisterListener...;  // Prior that you have to do it with recursion
    using Ts::sendEvent...;           // class EventBus<T, Rest...> : T, EventBus<Rest...> 
};
```

With usage:

```
EventBus<EventHandler<AListener, AEvent>, EventHandler<BListener, BEvent>> eventBus;
```

Btw, `Event` is probably dependent of `Listener`, so having `typename Listener::Event` seems appropriate and remove all `Event` template parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tuple and some type traits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename x_Event> class
t_EventTrait;

template<typename ... x_Listener> class
t_EventBus
{
    private: ::std::tuple<::std::vector<x_Listener *>...> m_listeners;

    public: template<typename xx_Listener> void
    Register_Listener(xx_Listener & listener)
    {
        ::std::get<::std::vector<xx_Listener *>>(m_listeners).emplace_back(&listener);
    }

    public: template<typename x_Event> void
    Send_Event(x_Event & event)
    {
        for(auto p_listener: ::std::get<::std::vector<typename t_EventTrait<x_Event>::t_Listener *>>(m_listeners))
        {
            p_listener->On_Event(event);
        }
    }
};

struct t_EventA {};
struct t_ListenerA { void On_Event(t_EventA &) { ::std::cout << "handling A\n"; } };
template<> class t_EventTrait<t_EventA>{ public: using t_Listener = t_ListenerA; };

struct t_EventB {};
struct t_ListenerB { void On_Event(t_EventB &) { ::std::cout << "handling B\n"; } };
template<> class t_EventTrait<t_EventB>{ public: using t_Listener = t_ListenerB; };

int main()
{
    t_EventBus<t_ListenerA, t_ListenerB> bus{};
    t_ListenerA a{};
    bus.Register_Listener(a);
    t_EventA ea{};
    bus.Send_Event(ea);
    t_ListenerB b{};
    bus.Register_Listener(b);
    t_EventB eb{};
    bus.Send_Event(eb);
    return 0;   
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LgsTiwcSoa9iu5bF)

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can use a variadic template

```
template<class... MoreEventPairs> class EventBus {};

template<class Listener, class Event>
class EventBus<Listener, Event>
{
    private:
        std::vector<Listener *> Listeners;
    public:

       EventBus() {};
       ~EventBus() {};

       void registerListener(Listener& listener) {};    // dummy implementations here
       void unregisterListener(Listener& listener) {};
       void sendEvent(Event event) {};
};

template<class Listener, class Event, class ... MoreEventPairs>
class EventBus<Listener, Event, MoreEventPairs ...> : public EventBus<Listener, Event>,
                                                      public EventBus<MoreEventPairs ...>
{
    public:

        //  these are needed so name resolution works
        //    one needed for each function, on both inheritance paths

        using EventBus<Listener, Event>::registerListener;
        using EventBus<Listener, Event>::unregisterListener;
        using EventBus<Listener, Event>::sendEvent;

        using EventBus<MoreEventPairs ...>::registerListener;
        using EventBus<MoreEventPairs ...>::unregisterListener;
        using EventBus<MoreEventPairs ...>::sendEvent;
};

//   construct as

EventBus<ListenerA, EventA, ListenerB, EventB> bus;
```

This works by essentially peeling two types at a time from the parameter pack.   It will not compile if you supply an odd number of types when constructing  (e.g. leave off an `Event` type).    You can specialise handling for a particular type of `Listener` or associated `Event` by using specialisation of the two-parameter template.

Before C++11, you could use multiple inheritance, but would need to construct the `EventBus` class separately.   This is more effort to maintain, due to need to replicate code to extend.

```
template<class Listener, class Event> class ListenerBus
{
   private:
      std::vector<Listener *> Listeners;
   public:

      ListenerBus() {};
      ~ListenerBus() {};

      void registerListener(Listener& listener) {};    // dummy implementations here
      void unregisterListener(Listener& listener) {};
      void sendEvent(Event event) {};
};

//  AListener, AEvent, etc are concrete classes
class EventBus : public ListenerBus<AListener, AEvent>,
                 public ListenerBus<BListener, BEvent>
                // list other types here
{
    public:

      using ListenerBus<AListener, AEvent>::registerListener;
      using ListenerBus<AListener, AEvent>::unregisterListener;
      using ListenerBus<AListener, AEvent>::sendEvent;

      using ListenerBus<BListener, BEvent>::registerListener;
      using ListenerBus<BListener, BEvent>::unregisterListener;
      using ListenerBus<BListener, BEvent>::sendEvent;

      // need to replicate above for every base class for name resolution
};

//   construct as

EventBus bus;
```

The `registerListener()`, `unregisterListener()`, and `sendEvent()` member functions are all non-`virtual` since you don't want them to be over-ridden by `EventBus`  (which will then be affected by the hiding rule).

In addition to assuming no inheritance relationships between any `Listener` or `Event` classes, both approaches above assume the `Listener` and `Event` classes are all distinct types  (i.e. no `Listener` class or `Event` class listed more than once).   The most likely outcome, if you break that assumption, will be that calls of some of the member functions will become ambiguous.

Comment: This won't work because invocation of any method from the base class (such as `bus.sendEvent(...`) would be ambiguous.

Comment: @VTT - not with the assumption that the event types are distinct.   The OP assumed something similar.

Comment: Even with assumption that event types are distinct. Ambiguity will happen during member name resolution, prior to overload selection. And in order to fix it you must bring using declarations for all the members from all the base classes which will make entire thing pointless.